# fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1325)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

When i compiled the code the error pointing to the following class . The error is higlighted on two lines as below :
    tm validFrom{};
    tm validUntil{};

```
struct t_SslCertData final
{
    struct t_Contact
    {
        TCHAR Organization[256];
        TCHAR Unit[256];
        TCHAR CommonName[256];
        TCHAR Mail[256];
        TCHAR Country[256];
        TCHAR StateProvince[256];
        TCHAR Town[256];
        TCHAR Other[1024];
    } subject, issuer;



//Below are the lines where compiler highlights the error

    tm validFrom{};
    tm validUntil{};

    unsigned char hash[20];

    int verificationResult;
    int verificationDepth;

    int priv_data; //Internal data, do not modify
};
```

Answer (score 3):

i don't see any errors in shared code, you should go to "Settings" and change the optimization settings (disable it, if you can). This error occurs once in a while.

Comment: This solved my problem. Its the wierdest thing.
I disabled the optimization and the build finally succeeded.
The funny thing is that when I changed back the optimization settings to what they were when it was failing, the build still succeeded.
Apparently this is a Visual Studio bug of some sort.

Comment: Change: Whole Program Optimization From: Use Link Time Code Generation to: No Whole Program Optimization

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **Retarget Solution**

[image: img]

I came across this problem when I was compiling Unreal Engine 4 with my own code.
It takes me a lot of work to figure it out.

Latest IDE is fine. Both vs2017 and vs2019 installed is fine. Your windows environment is fine. Overclocked CPU is fine.

By the way I solve it, **I guess** it is the windows SDK the projects in your solution  using is different with each other that lead to a **"compiler inner error"**.

Comment: Can you please include image in the answer rather than a link to it.

Comment: @ASR New users cannot. It is up to us to embed them after the fact.