# error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler in Debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am facing this error message:

> error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler

It appears just in the `Debug` mode. There is no clue about why this is happening. The compiler does not give me any hint to the line. When I click on the error it is take me to blank file called `xxx.obj`.

**The platform:**

- Visual Studio 2013
- Intel i7
- Windows 8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Yes, self-answered question notwithstanding.

Comment: were there deleted comments?

Comment: Sorry I could not understand your comment. I thought it was a reply to someone else

Comment: If you are just saying that I should propose a complete question. This error is a strange one which does not give you any clue. Even microsoft recommended to update your visual studio to get rid of it. In other words, there is no more clues that I can attach to my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076494/fatal-error-c1001-an-internal-error-has-occurred-in-the-compiler   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091662/vc-internal-compiler-error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957921/fatal-error-c1001-an-internal-error-has-occurred-in-the-compiler-compiler-file

Comment: You should at least post a way of triggering the problem.

Comment: No one can. or you want me to post 5000+ lines of  code ?

Comment: No, **post a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).**

Comment: I think you just do not want to listen.. perhaps.. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the problem after digging into the warnings I am getting. There was a suspecios one which is:

> warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' :
>   conversion from 'T' to 'T&'

This warning is because of this line:

```
auto x = foo(bar{});
```

the function foo is declared as follow:

```
int foo(bar&);
```

This behavouir is not standared as was discuueed here: [Is it possible to know if the parameter was defaulted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653230/is-it-possible-to-know-if-the-parameter-was-defaulted/) . However, MSVS supports this behaviour as non-standard extension.

Usually it works well without any problem but due to non-known thing in this project it did not work.

After correcting it with these two lines:

```
bar temp{};
auto x = foo(temp);
```

Everything worked well.

Comment: You got it silenced but the actual example that triggers internal issue in compiler wasn't discovered.

Comment: Yes that it is right. However, I just wanted to notify that using this extension may  result in undesirable behaviour.